# How to convert a time with string format to Time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, prediction

There is a dataframe with a column `time` that is `string` and a `date` that is `int` from 1 to 140.

[image]

time is a string:

```
0         00:05:24
1         00:05:43
2         00:06:34
3         00:06:50
4         00:06:55
```

I want to create a model of `Random Forest` to predict class `h`, but as we can see the date and time column are not useful and I cannot use them in `Random Forest`. I need to somehow combine these two column to a new one to make them useful in prediction.

Comment: what does `date` represent here?

Comment: what is the significance of 'date'?

Comment: `date` is an `int` number from 1 to 140 representing the date that `a` (is unique id) occurred in `time` in `date`.

Comment: `date` needed for calculating some intervals.

Comment: Please mention the relationship between 'date' and actual date. How you got this value? Because there should be some mapping..

Comment: consider this day as `date` 1 for 140 future days that in each day `a` occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything as numerical features, then whatever date represents (I'm assuming you are numbering days relative to some zero point?), you could add time on as a fraction of a day (time in seconds / number of seconds in a day).

Dummy data:

```
>>> df
13:    date      time
0    23  00:05:43
1    45  00:06:34
2    67  00:06:50
3    89  00:06:55
```

Calculate time fraction, add it to the date to make a 'time':

```
>>> df['seconds'] = df.time.apply(pd.to_timedelta).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
>>> df['of_day'] = df.seconds / (24*60*60)
>>> df['datetime_number'] = df.date + df.of_day
>>> df
17:    date      time  seconds    of_day  datetime_number
0    23  00:05:43    343.0  0.003970        23.003970
1    45  00:06:34    394.0  0.004560        45.004560
2    67  00:06:50    410.0  0.004745        67.004745
3    89  00:06:55    415.0  0.004803        89.004803
```